# LWC How to display address values in lightning-input-field?

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce, lwc

I have **changedFields** object with the structure like following:

changed fields: {"Name":"Test Practice Test","ReasonForUpdate":"Test","BillingAddress":{"BillingCity":"Beaumont","BillingCountry":"United States","BillingCountryCode":"US","BillingGeocodeAccuracy":null,"BillingLatitude":null,"BillingLongitude":null,"BillingPostalCode":"77705","BillingState":"TX","BillingStateCode":"TX","BillingStreet":"Test Street change 123"}}

I would like to display BillingAddress values in lightning-input-field but instead it's empty:
[FORM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhn8t.png)

I tried adding {changedFields.BillingAddress} as value of lightning-input-field and I was expecting it will be shown in the form:

```
<lightning-record-edit-form if:true={isPractice} record-id={recordId} object-api-name={objectApiName}>
    <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Name" name="Name" value={changedFields.Name} onchange={handleFormInputChange}></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Phone" name="Phone" value={changedFields.Phone} type="phone" onchange={handleFormInputChange}></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Fax" name="Fax" value={changedFields.Fax} onchange={handleFormInputChange}></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="ShippingAddress" name="ShippingAddress" value={ShippingAddress} onchange={handleFormInputChange}></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="BillingAddress" name="BillingAddress" value={changedFields.BillingAddress} onchange={handleFormInputChange}></lightning-input-field>
    </div>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

I have the same functionality with Name which has similar structure to Address and it works fine.
How can I achieve this with Address? I'd rather avoid using separate fields or lightning-input-address because it would need rebuild of few components.

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import getAccount from '@salesforce/apex/ChangeRequestController.getAccount';

export default class ChangeRequestEditForm extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
@api objectApiName;
@api changedFieldsBack;
@track changedFields = {};

@track
isPractice = false;
@track
isProvider = false;

@wire(getAccount, { accountId: '$recordId' })
accountRecordType({ data }) {
    if (data) {
        if (data.RecordType.Name === "Practice") {
            this.isPractice = true;
        } else if (data.RecordType.Name === 'Provider') {
            this.isProvider = true;
        }
    }
}

connectedCallback(){
    if (Object.keys(this.changedFieldsBack).length !== 0) {
        Object.assign(this.changedFields, this.changedFieldsBack);
        var billingTest = {};
        billingTest.BillingCity = "city";
        billingTest.BillingCountry = "United States";
        billingTest.BillingCountryCode = "US";
        billingTest.BillingGeocodeAccuracy = null;
        billingTest.BillingLatitude = null;
        billingTest.BillingLongitude = null;
        billingTest.BillingPostalCode = "77705";
        billingTest.BillingState = "TX";
        billingTest.BillingStateCode = "TX";
        billingTest.BillingStreet = "street";
        this.changedFields = { ...this.changedFields, BillingAddress: billingTest };

        console.log('changed fields: ' + JSON.stringify(this.changedFields));
        console.log('billing address: ' + JSON.stringify(this.changedFields.BillingAddress));
    }
}

handleFormInputChange(event){
    this.changedFields[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    const valuechangedEvent = new CustomEvent("progressvaluechange", {
            detail: this.changedFields
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(valuechangedEvent);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're probably setting changedFields something like this right?

```
this.changedFields.BillingAddress = newValue;
```

This won't work b/c the reference hasn't changed.  You will have to do something like this to get the ui to react:

```
this.changedFields = { ...this.changedFields, BillingAddress: newValue };
```

Comment: I don't think that's it. This is how the code looks like now - please take a look at the last picture.

Comment: Your code is in connectedCallback - when does the changedFields variable get set?  It would be good if you could just post text instead of screenshots for your html and js to better assist you.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new here. I modified post, so now you can see code. handleFormInputChange function handle changes of the form. After clicking "Next" button, other component shows up. Then user can click "Back" button and values from changedFields should appear on UI, not the original record values. Let me know if that makes sense! As I mentioned it works with any other field except for addresses.

Comment: I added "billingTest" variable just to test displaying.

Comment: ah - you know what, it probably has something to do with `BillingAddress` being a compound field. I'm not sure what you're doing will work.  If anything, I would try `billingTest.City` instead of `billingTest.BillingCity`.  Maybe that will work?  Otherwise, you may need to split out the input into separate fields.